# Vim replace specific character in a word in a line

Tags: shell, vim

I want to replace `;` to `,` in  a file .

```
Query ; Query Time ; Lock Time ; Rows Examined

Closed User Count ; 19.530083 ; 0.000090 ; 64;49;246
```

Expected Output:

```
Query ; Query Time ; Lock Time ; Rows Examined

Closed User Count ; 19.530083 ; 0.000090 ; 64,49,246
```

I use vim substitution to replace. But , I don't how to replace in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:%s#\([^ ]\);\([^ ]\)#\1,\2#g
```

Explanation:

The `%` aplies the command in every line.

Substitute command does not care which delimiter you use. It uses the first character after `s`. When (a lot of) backslashes are used, I use e.g. `#`.

It takes ("not-a-space" ; "not-a-space") and replaces it by (that 1st "not-a-space" , the 2nd "not-a-space")

`g` at the end of the line makes it replace all the occurences per line (not just the first)

Comment: I really like the custom field delimiter! That's a handy tip to make things easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:

> :%s/(\d*);(\d*);(\d*)$/\1,\2,\3/gc

Explained:

`%s/search/replace/gc` - will find all instances of search and swap them with replace. the c at the end makes it so vi will prompt you for each change

`\(\d*\);\(\d*\);\(\d*\)` - as many numbers until you hit a semicolon, three times. the escaped parens will capture the output

`\1,\2,\3` - escaped numbers give you the data we captured in the search string

Comment: Do you think it's worth anchoring on ``$`` so it picks up end of line numbers? Just in case OP hasn't shared all instances of change required.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all ";" are between digits:

```
:%s/\(\d\);\(\d\)/\1,\2/g
```

Or if you are looking for ";" not preceding by space

```
:%s/ \@<!;/,/g
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant of Billy's answer that matches "one or more" digit instead of "0 or more":

```
:%s/\v(\d+);(\d+);(\d+)/\1,\2,\3
```

and another one that matches "at least 2" digits:

```
:%s/\v(\d{2,});(\d{2,});(\d{2,})/\1,\2,\3
```